MERN Project Fails to Build on Render.com but Works Locally
I have a MERN project that compiles and runs perfectly fine on my local machine, but I’m running into issues when deploying it on Render.com.
The error message I’m getting during the build on Render says it’s looking for a ../controllers/chatControllers.js file in the src/... folder. However, in my source code, the file is a TypeScript file (.ts), not a JavaScript file (.js), because the .ts files haven’t been compiled yet.
It seems that Render is trying to access the .js file before the TypeScript compilation happens. Locally, the compilation works correctly, so I assume this might be related to how the build process is handled on Render.
Here are the details:
Locally, I run npm run build, which compiles my TypeScript files to JavaScript before launching the app, and everything works fine.
On Render, the build seems to fail when it’s looking for the .js file even though the .ts files haven’t been compiled yet.
Questions:
How can I ensure that Render correctly compiles the TypeScript files before looking for the .js files during the build process?
Is there a specific build or deploy setting in Render that I need to configure to handle TypeScript compilation properly?
Thank you in advance for your help!
Here’s a snippet from the build log on Render.com:
==> Running build command 'pnpm i && pnpm build'...
.../bcrypt@5.1.1/node_modules/bcrypt install$ node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
.../bcrypt@5.1.1/node_modules/bcrypt install: [bcrypt] Success: "/opt/render/project/src/backend/node_modules/.pnpm/bcrypt@5.1.1/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
.../bcrypt@5.1.1/node_modules/bcrypt install: Done
dependencies:
+ bcrypt 5.1.1
+ concurrently 8.2.2
+ cookie-parser 1.4.6
+ cors 2.8.5
+ dotenv 16.4.5
+ express 4.19.2
+ express-validator 7.1.0
+ jsonwebtoken 9.0.2
+ mongoose 8.4.0
+ morgan 1.10.0
+ openai 4.47.1
devDependencies:
+ @types/bcrypt 5.0.2
+ @types/cookie-parser 1.4.7
+ @types/cors 2.8.17
+ @types/express 4.17.21
+ @types/jsonwebtoken 9.0.6
+ @types/node 20.12.12
+ nodemon 3.1.1
+ ts-node 10.9.2
+ typescript 5.4.5
Done in 6.9s
> backend@1.0.0 build /opt/render/project/src/backend
> tsc
src/routes/chatRoutes.ts(5,8): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../controllers/chatControllers.js' or its corresponding type declarations.
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 2.
==> Build failed 

my tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "src/index"]
}

Thanks in advance for your help!
